# Camera Shake Not Activating Unreal C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am trying to set a camera shake for my character in Unreal C++.

Currently, I declare the instance variable in my header class.

Using log outputs, the code is reaching the right location in the OnFire() function, meaning none of the pointers are null.  But the camera shake doesn't work.

```
UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
UCameraShake* CShake;
```

// And here is how I call it

```
void AZombieCharacter::BeginPlay(){
    SetUpCameraShake();
}


...

void AZombieCharacter::OnFire() {

...
    auto CTRLR = UGameplayStatics::GetPlayerController(GetWorld(), 0);

    if (CTRLR) {
        auto CM = CTRLR->PlayerCameraManager;
        if (CM) {
            CM->PlayCameraShake(CShake->GetClass(), 1.0f);
        }
        else {
            UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CANNOT FIND CM"));
        }
    }
    else {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("CANNOT FIND CTRLR"));
    }
}
...
void AZombieCharacter::SetUpCameraShake() {


    CShake = UCameraShake::StaticClass()->GetDefaultObject<UCameraShake>();

    CShake->OscillationDuration = 4.f;
    CShake->OscillationBlendInTime = 0.5f;
    CShake->OscillationBlendOutTime = 0.5f;

    CShake->RotOscillation.Pitch.Amplitude = FMath::RandRange(5.0f, 10.0f);
    CShake->RotOscillation.Pitch.Frequency = FMath::RandRange(25.0f, 35.0f);

    CShake->RotOscillation.Yaw.Amplitude = FMath::RandRange(5.0f, 10.0f);
    CShake->RotOscillation.Yaw.Frequency = FMath::RandRange(25.0f, 35.0f);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play Camera Shake Accepts an `UClass` / `TSubClassOf<UCameraShake>` knowing that would expect us to think that this function would eventually construct a new object and ignore the default object options.

I would recommend to subclass the `UCameraShake` class and use `TSubClassOf` to store your class type instead of the pointer like `CShake`. As it may be garbage collected without you knowing who knows?

Here is a C++ tutorial on UCameraShake's.
https://unrealcpp.com/camera-shake/

The reason your shake is not playing is likely having no actual parameters passed to the shake. Only the default ones despite your try to set the default values, it does not seem to take it into account for newly created objects.

Comment: Thanks for replying.
I did see that tutorial but I'm trying to do it without creating an entirely new class as they do in the tutorial.
Any suggestions?

Comment: As the ue4 docs says you should not use this function. The returned ptr is immutable (you can't really change the values of the object you're expecting to change this way). You must make your own class to override the default setting afaik

Comment: UCameraShake const* const ShakeCDO = GetDefault<UCameraShake>(ShakeClass)

Comment: The shake class is used this way in the camera modifier class this may give you some hints

Comment: https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/7d9919ac7bfd80b7483012eab342cb427d60e8c9/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/Camera/CameraModifier_CameraShake.cpp